# Server-side preprocessor for crisp nice Font/Text like in photoshop

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, css

is there any way to render Text/Fonts with a preprocessor or something like these to get nice fonts with glow, grandient, crisp like in photoshop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 to mimic the layer styles or blending options that you would use in photoshop. Alternatively you can use [csshat](https://csshat.com/) which allows you to mock up your layer styles in photoshop and then convert them into css3 for you. Very handy

Comment: Forgot to mention it supports  SASS, LESS or Stylus. WHich is what your question was :)

Comment: it's costs money and do not help me. the rendering of the font inside the browser is still not crisp or gradient.

Comment: If you could provide an example or an image of what you want to achieve then you may find more help. Here is an example of some gradiented text and other photoshop like effects (for chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/keZmF/12/

Comment: photoshop just render it better. The text goes trough some filters. Its not possible to archive this in photoshop. Just look at the corners of your text.